# 401: Deleted client on playstore build

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, expo, google-oauth

I have been developing an app that uses google oauth through firebase. The login works perfectly on a apk standalone build and on a expo development build but on my playstore build it throws this error:
Error 401: deleted_client. I am using the same credentials and keystore on all builds and everything else is the same. What is the cause of this error? How do I fix it?

My google auth config:

```
const [request, response, promptAsync] = Google.useAuthRequest({
    useProxy: true,
    expoClientId: '', //My expo client id
    androidClientId: '', //My standalone client id
})
```